# c# LINQ - Selecting distinct sub object

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have the following object structure represented by c# classes:

```
[
    {
        Title: "",
        Year: 1977,
        Categories: ["Action", "Adventure", "Fantasy"],
        Score: 96
    }
]
```

This json is serialized to an `IEnumerable<TitleItem>` object, where `Categories` is an `IList<string>` object.

From that collection of `TitleItem` objects I would like to get a new `IList<string>` of distinct categories. How can this be done?

Comment: @NicoRiff - I guess because this question doesn't show any attempt to solve problem?... SO is not a code service and one should show effort

Comment: @GiladGreen I know how SO works and also know how it should work. Lately you get easily downvoted downvoted. There is a very sharp line where you don´t get downvoted. It is very dissapointing primarilly to new users

Comment: @GiladGreen What kind of effort should he have shown? If he doesn't know about `SelectMany` or  `Distinct` there's very little you can do. I think the question is fair, properly created and formatted. Do we really need to know whether he has read and understood the entire LINQ-spec?

Comment: @Kenneth - In this case, IMHO, a simple search on google with words along "C# linq nested collection distinct" or anything similar will result if several similar questions. So showing effort is showing why similar questions didn't help to solve it. And as for reading through some documentation... Yap :) I think it is a good idea in any case

Comment: @NicoRiff - True.. Which is why I don't immediately download... But still SO How To Ask and the Tour cover what is needed for a question to be considered good..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
collection.SelectMany(x=>x.Categories).District().ToList()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx) to "flatten" the lists of categories and then use [`Distinct`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var result = titleItems.SelectMany(item => item.Categories).Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a `SelectMany` and then a `distinct` on that `IEnumerable`:

```
IEnumerable<TitleItem> items = getItemsFromSomeWhere();
var uniqueTitles = items.SelectMany(i => i.Categories).Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the query that will return distinct of categories

```
class TitleItem {
    public string Title;
    public string Year;
    public float score;
    public IList<string> Categories;
}

var titleItems = new List<TitleItem>();
var titleItem1 = new TitleItem();
titleItem1.Categories = new List<string>();
titleItem1.Categories.Add("Action");
titleItem1.Categories.Add("Adventure");
titleItem1.Categories.Add("Fantasy");
titleItem1.Categories.Add("Action");
titleItems.Add(titleItem1);

var titleItem2 = new TitleItem();
titleItem2.Categories = new List<string>();
titleItem2.Categories.Add("Action");

titleItems.SelectMany(a => a.Categories).Distinct();
```